# Get all the attributes related to one Model as JSON

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-4

I  have this model for Author:

```
<?php


class Author extends Eloquent {    

  public function albums()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Album')->withPivot('city');
  }

}
```

And this model for Album:

```
<?php


class Album extends Eloquent {

  public function artist()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Artist');
  }

  public function authors()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Author')->withPivot('city');
  }

}
```

To get a model I can easily do this:

`$author = Author::where('name','=','Chester Bennington')->first()->toJson();`

and it'll return something like this (as JSON):

`{"id":3,"name":"Chester Bennington","created_at":"2014-06-29 16:10:21","updated_at":"2014-06-29 16:10:21"}`

See that it won't return the albums related to it. To get the albums I would have to do this: `$author->albums->toJson()`

Since I'm doing an API and it returns everything as JSON, is there a way to get the model and ALL its attributes without specifying which ones to get??

Comment: Have you tried `$author = json_encode(Author::with('albums')->where('name','=','Chester Bennington')->first());`

Comment: That just answered my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [eager load the relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) you want, it'll be included in your JSON:

```
Author::with('albums')->where('name', 'Chester Bennington')->first()->toJson();
```